# What are the points of a waistcoat?

Tags: word-meaning

What are the points of a waistcoat? From an English translation of Kafka's Trial

> "I think," said the man, who was elegantly dressed and whose appearance was made especially impressive with a grey waistcoat that had two long, **sharply tailored points**, "the gentleman is feeling unwell because of the atmosphere here, so the best thing, and what he would most prefer, would be not to take him to the sick room but get him out of the offices altogether."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The waistcoat in this picture has two points at the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are pictures of vests (almost the same as waistcoats):
[Amazon *vests*](https://www.amazon.com/waistcoat-men/s?k=waistcoat%20for%20men)

I think the points are the inverted triangles at the bottom front closure of the garment. A vest may or may not have such points.

Comment: 'Vest' is just the US term for the British waistcoat [should be pronounced 'wess-kit', but no-one ever does any more]. To us, a 'vest' is what the US would call an undershirt [though usually sleeveless, with small sleeves we'd just call it a t-shirt]  [Amazon UK link 'vest for men'](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=vest+for+men&crid=2GCHH8UKAP0RK&sprefix=vest+for+men%2Caps%2C87&ref=nb_sb_noss_1)

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - I was intrigued to discover that the 'vest' that my father wore to the beach at Margate on holiday is called a 'wife-beater' in America. He never beat my mother that I know about.

Comment: Interesting - whereas to us, 'wife beater' is Stella Artois ;))